# pythonにおけるmultidictによる２つの値の比較

Tags: python, データ構造

```
I,p=multidict({1:9,2:4,3:7,4:3})
W,w=multidict({1:3,2:5,3:4,4:1})
```

の互いの2つの値を比較し, 条件を満たすもの出力するプログラムを作りたいです.

```
for i in  I:
    if p.values(i)<w.values(i):
        print(i)
```

とすると,

```
TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

と出てくるのでわかりません.
どこを変更すればよいですか.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from gurobipy import multidict

I, p = multidict({1:9, 2:4, 3:7, 4:3})
W, w = multidict({1:3, 2:5, 3:4, 4:1})

for i in I:
    if i in w and p[i] < w[i]:
        print(i)

#
2
```

Or

```py
from gurobipy import multidict

I, p = multidict({1:9, 2:4, 3:7, 4:3})
W, w = multidict({1:3, 2:5, 3:4, 4:1})

keys = [i for i in p if i in w and p[i] < w[i]]
print(keys)

#
[2]
```